# kafka connect hdfs sink lag monitoring

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I understand within confluent 5.X and higher consumer offsets are now only committed back to the consumer group periodically for the connect hdfs sink connector. This makes consumer lag monitoring not entirely accurate as it uses WAls to keep track of its current offsets within HDFS itself.

If this is truly the case, is there another place to keep track of the sinks lag that does not involve reading the files out of HDFS but from the connector itself?
Or am I missing something and consumer group lag is always up to date and the proper way to track progress?

version:
confluent community edition 5.5.2
confluent hdfs 2 sink connector 10.1.1

Comment: AFAIK, the consumer group information is correct. If a WAL file fails for some reason, then it'll need to reset to the group value

Comment: I had thought it was only committing offsets back to __consumer_offsets periodically but from reviewing this PR it looks to be committing the offsets once the HDFS files have been finalized. So ignoring what is in flight from the WALs the consumer lag is accurate for what is complete. 
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/pull/417